# How to export specific price and volume data from the LMAX level 2 widget to excel

Tags: excel, trading, lmax

**Background -**
I am not  a programmer. 
I do trade spot forex on an intraday basis.
I am willing to learn programming

**Specific Query -** 
I would like to know how to export into <kbd>Excel</kbd> in real time 'top of book' price and volume data as displayed on the LMAX level 2 widget/frame on - 
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lmax-widget/website-widget-quote-prof-flex.html?a=rTWcS34L5WRQkHtC

In essence I am looking to export

1. price and volume data where the coloured flashes occur.
2. price and volume data for when the coloured flashes do not occur.

I understand that 1) and 2) will encompass all the top of book prices and volume. However i would like to keep 1) and 2) separate/distinguished as far as data collection is concerned.

Time period for which the collected data intends to be stored  -> 2-3 hours.

**What kind of languages do I need to know to do the above?**
I understand that I need to be an advanced excel user too.

**Long term goals -**
I intend to use the above information to make discretionary intraday trading decisions.
In the long run I will get more involved with creating an algo or indicator to help with the decision making process, which would include the information above.

I have understood that one needs to know coding to get involved in activities such as the above. Hence I have started learning C ++. More so to get a hang/feel for coding.
I have been searching all over the web as to where to start in this endeavor. However I am quite confused and overwhelmed with all the information.
Hence apart from the specific data export query, any additional guidelines would also be helpful.

As of now I use <kbd>MT4</kbd> to trade. Hence I  believe to do the above  -  I will need more than just MT4.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes,** `MetaTrader4` is still **not able** ( in spite of all white-label-ed Terminals' OrderBook Add-On(s) marketing and PR efforts ) to provide an **`OrderBook-L2/DoM-data`** into your `MQL4` / `NewMQL4` algorithm for any decision making. Third party software tools' integration is needed to make `MQL4`-code aware of the real-time `L2/DoM-data`.

**LMAX widget** has impressive look & feel, however for your Excel export it requires a lot of programming efforts to re-use it for an automated scanner to produce data for **1** & **2** while there may be some further, non-technical, troubles on legal / operational restrictions for automated scanner to be operated on such data-source. To bring an example, the data-publisher policy restrict automated Options-pricing scanners for options on { FTSE | CAC | AMS | DAX }, may re-visit the online published data-sources no more than once a quarter of an hour and get blocked / black-listed otherwise. So a care and a proper data-source engineering is in place.

**Size of data collection** is another issue. Excel has some restrictions on an amount of rows/columns that may get imported. Large data-files, the more the CSV-imports may strike these limits. `L2/DoM-data`, collected for 2-3 hours just for one single FX Major may go beyond such a limit, as there are many records per second ( tens, if not hundreds, with just a few miliseconds between them ). Static file-size of collected data-records take typically several minutes to just get written on disk, so proper distributed processing `data-flow`-design and non-blocking-`fileIO` engineering is a must.

**Real-time system design** is the right angle to view the problem solution approach, rather than just some programming language excersise. Having mastered some programming language is a great move, nevertheless, so called robust real-time system design, and Trading software is such a domain, requires, with all respect, a lot more insights and hands-on experience than to make an `MQL4` code run multi-thread-ed & multi-process-ed with a few DLL services for a Cloud/Grid-based distributed processing system.

### How much real-time traffic is expected to be there?

For just a raw idea, what the Market can produce per second, per milisecon, per microsecond, let's view a NYNEX traffic analysis for one instrument:

**One second can have this wild relief:**
[image: REAL-TIME TRAFFIC PER SECOND]

**And once looking into 5-msec sampling:**
[image: REAL-TIME TRAFFIC PER MILISECOND]

### How to export

1. Check if the `data-source` owner legally permits your automated processing.
2. Create your own real-time `DataPump` software, independent of the HTML-wrapped Widget
3. Create your own 'DB-store' to efficiently off-load scanned data-records from real-time `DataPump`
4. Test the  live `data-source` >> `DataPump` >> `DB-store` performance & robustness on being able to serve error-free a 24/6 duty for several FX Majors in parallel
5. Integrate your `DataPump` fed `DB-store` local `data-source` for on-line/off-line interactions with your preferred { MT4 | Excel | quantitative-analytics } package
6. Integrate a monitoring of any production environment irregularity in your real-time processing pipeline, which may range from network issues, VPN / hosting issues, data-source availability issues to an unexpected change in the scanned data-source format/access conditions.

Comment: That was a big help and very insightful. Would it be possible to suggest/recommend a few languages to look into for the above work. As I understand that different languages have different strengths.
For example I am quite sure I will need to create some form of database and based on my personal research ( which can be flawed) I will have to learn something like SQL.
In this case I guess it would be relevant for the 'DB store' component.
If there is any other software or application where I will be able to perform all of the above in an integrated manner, please do feel to make suggestions.

Comment: **Good to know you consider it helpfull**. Programming languages typically spark battles as having many fans, a lot of evangelists, a few fanatics, many opinion-based opponents and may have some fact-based opponent(s). The language is IMHO the last thing to decide for any Project about. There are more language-dependent issues: Is the Language capable? What will be a cost of the new Language learning & adaptation of all tools to get solid craftmanship with a new Language? Will the Project be developed with small/big number of people? What is their previous practice with respective Language(s)?

Comment: Well your comment grew in length. It will require a bit longer text to answer it.Be rather carefull about the real-time and off-line tasks. A single `DB-store` typically cannot perform reasonably well on both and so database need not mean any classical steam-powered RDBMS. For real-time sensitive operations, some in-memory datastructures will outperform any general purpose RDBMS as not having their "overhead", while for off-line ( typically analytics, quantitative modelling and back-testing ) work, there are lot of tools well suited for data-processing while not-being an SQL-interpret on RDBMS